# how to change the alterbox and confirm box buttons and Icons in asp.net2.0?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am writting like that in asp.net2.0 .cs file , after executing code disply alert message 'Invoice Created Successfully' but warning icon displayed in that message but it display information icon and same as confirm box also pls help me

```
Response.Write("<script>alert('Invoice Created Successfully');</script>");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complete article can be found at

http://raufnicole.wordpress.com/2011/07/08/jquery-jalert/

```
<script src=”jquery/jquery-1.5.1.min.js” type=”text/javascript”></script>

<script src=”jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js” type=”text/javascript”></script>
<script src=”jquery/jquery.alerts.js” type=”text/javascript”></script>

<link href=”jquery/jquery.alerts.css” rel=”stylesheet” type=”text/css” />

<script type=”text/javascript”>
$(document).ready(function() {
jAlert(‘This is a custom alert box’, ‘Alert Dialog’);
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form id=”form1″ runat=”server”>
<div>
<a href=”#” >Click</a>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a custom icon, you can use a Jquery Alert and Confirm, Take a look at a Demo here:

[JQuery Alert Boxes : ( Confirm Alert Prompt ) | 99Points](http://demos.99points.info/jquery_alert_box/#)

Download this from here...

[JQuery Alert Dialog Boxes With Simple Demo | 99Points](http://www.99points.info/2010/04/jquery-alert-dialog-boxes-with-demos/)

Comment: hi,pls send me how to write the code and send me which librarys are added in asp.net2.0

Comment: From the Second link you can download the library.

Comment: hi,Response.Write("<script>alert('Invoice Created Successfully');</script>"); how to write like that in jquery i am click the button after if condition it will work